Changing design of nav bar in responsive design
Hello fellow developers,
I’m currently building a website using WordPress without any plugins or themes—entirely through hardcoding. I’ve implemented a responsive navigation bar, and everything appears to function well in the developer view.
However, I’m encountering an issue: when I click on any of the navigation links to access other pages, the design changes unexpectedly. Additionally, I am unable to click on any of the navigation links afterward.
Could anyone advise on possible causes or solutions for this behavior? I appreciate any guidance.
Thank you!
this is my nav bar


 .navbar {
        background-color: #ECEDE8;
    }

    .navbar-brand,
    .nav-link {
        color: black !important;
        margin-top: 20px;
        font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    .nav-link.active {
        color: #8AA899 !important;
    }

    .nav-link:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: #8AA899;
        transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }

    .nav-link:hover:after,
    .nav-link.active:after {
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* Adjust brand image and nav links for small screens */
    @media (max-width: 767.98px) {
        .navbar-brand img {
            width: 150px;
        }

        .nav-link {
            margin-top: 10px;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
    }

    @media (max-width: 575.98px) {
        .navbar-brand img {
            width: 120px;
        }

        .nav-link {
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .navbar {
            padding: 10px 15px;
        }
    }
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2024/09/cropped-LOGO.png" style="width:200px;" /></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/about-us">About us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/contact-us">Contact us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>



so what do I need to do to fix and what should I look for to enhance this.
thankyou for the reply and have a great day.

If you temporarily eliminate the hover's, active's and media queries, what happens?

Does the posted code reproduce your problem, because I can't see anything happening that matches what you describe (other than the links opening entirely new pages, when clicked; which of course are different).

Good day,
It seems there are no issues with my code, correct?

If that’s the case, then when I implement this on my page using WordPress as the framework, The issue arises, when I switch pages in responsive view; the design changes unexpectedly.
